# Set task to upstream failed instead of running

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG with the following structure:

```
                     ________ branch_1_sensor___
                    |                           |
start ---branch_task                            |-------regular_task ----- complete
                    |________ branch_2_sensor___|
```

The state of the regular_task should be:

- run if any one of the sensors is successful
- skipped if both sensors are skipped
- upstream_failed if any one of the sensors fails

I set a trigger rule in the regular_task as `trigger_rule='one_success'` to achieve the first two states, but in the third case, it sets the task state to skipped, not upstream_failed. If I set the trigger rule to `trigger_rule='all_done'`, it will run (and fail) even if both sensors are skipped. Is there a better way to still have the task state be set to upstream_failed if one of the sensors fails?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that setting the trigger to `'none_failed'` achieves this exact scenario.

[Relevant source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.4/airflow/ti_deps/deps/trigger_rule_dep.py):

```
elif tr == TR.NONE_FAILED:
    if upstream_failed or failed:
        ti.set_state(State.UPSTREAM_FAILED, session)
    elif skipped == upstream:
        ti.set_state(State.SKIPPED, session)
```